# how to get the current year and the next year in asp?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys i am trying to display the current year and the next `year` in a label. i manage to show the current year using `SY.Text = Date.Now.Year` but how can i show the next year too ? for example the current year is 2017. i want to show it as : can you give me more idea ? or show me the proper way on how to this ?

S.Y: 2017-2018

how can i do this

[image: Like This]

ps: thankyou in advance.

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year;

Comment: Conversion from string "-" to type 'Double' is not valid

Comment: its error dude . how to fix ?

Comment: string str= DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year;

Comment: Can you show your code what did you tried, because error message tells that you using some other values in addition to years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here approach with correct typing

```
Dim nowYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
Label.Text = $"School year: {nowYear} - {nowYear + 1}"
```

In case you not using Roslyn compiler (older then Visual Studio 2015)

```
Label.Text = String.Format("School year: {0} - {1}", nowYear, nowYear + 1)
```

Do not use `+` as concatenate operator for strings, instead use `&` operator in vb.net.

Set `Option Strict On` in your project or write it in the first line of your code file. This option will help you recognize possible type conversion errors during compile time

Answer (score 0):

```
SY.Text = Date.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + (Date.Now.Year + 1).ToString()
```

Comment: it has an error mate ? Conversion from string "-" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentYear,futureYear;
DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
currentYear = theDate.Year;
theDate = theDate.AddYears(1);
futureYear =  theDate.Year;
SY.Text = currentYear.ToString()+"-"+currentYear.ToString();
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]